# Simple C program, but cannot give expected result

Tags: c, output

The program I am trying to get to work is "to convert minutes to years and days". Yes, **minutes are converted to years and days**. The code I tried to run is:

```
int main()
{
int minutes=0;
double minutesinayear=0.0;
double years=0.0;
double days=0.0;
printf("Enter minutes:");
scanf("%d", &minutes);
minutesinayear=(365*24*60);
years= (minutes / minutesinayear);
days=(minutes/60.0)/24.0;
printf("%d Minutes converted to years: %f and days: %f", &minutes, &years, &days);
return 0;
}
```

No matter what input the user gives, the output is always:

```
6356724 Minutes converted to years: 0.000000 and days: -0.000000
```

The Output is always the same as above. The error in build log is:

```
|15|warning: format '%lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 4 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]|
```

I have tried to change the format"%lf" to "%f", but it still doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: Don't need `&` on printf. Just the var name. With `&` you will get the address of var.

Comment: Check the return code from scanf and make sure it has set 1 argument. These return codes are there to help you diagnose problems. 
You should be getting warnings from your compiler that the type in your printf don't match. Don't ignore warnings - try to understand them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Comment: Aside: Since you are calculating years and days, you probably want the years to be a whole number (integer), but `years = (minutes / minutesinayear)` is likely to have a fractional part. And the days should be the left over minutes converted to days.

Comment: `minutesinayear=(365*24*60)` is doing integer arithmetic converting to floating point at the end. Change the constants to do all calculations as doubles.

Comment: Thank you all. I am a newbie and this mistake is really very noobish. All your comments have helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `&` on your `printf`. If you do so, you will get the address and not the value.

To fix that just:

`printf("%d Minutes converted to years: %f and days: %f", minutes, years, days);`

Comment: Oh! I am such a noob. I didn't see it before. I can't believe how I missed it :) Thank you!

Comment: If some answer was useful to you, please, consider to accept as correct.

Answer (score 2):

OK, a few words on some basics:

**printf** takes a string as an argument, with format specifiers, followed by the list of arguments to be replace.

e.g. `printf("a = %d",a);`, print the given string, replacing the first format-specifier (%), with the first argument (a), treated as an integer.

Other common formatting specifiers:

- `%d`  : integer
- `%l`  : long
- `%ul` : unsigned long
- `%f`  : float
- `%g`  : double
- `%s`  : string
- `%p`  : pointer

Your error is that you didn't ask printf to print the value of `minutes`, `years`, `days` but the value of their *address*.

---

**Remember:** each variable has an address (where it is stored) and the way to get it would be via `&var` (assuming your variable is named `var`).

---

To make your program work, all you have to do is **replace this line**:

```
printf("%d Minutes converted to years: %f and days: %f", &minutes, &years, &days);
```

**with:**

```
printf("%d Minutes converted to years: %f and days: %f", minutes, years, days);
```

Comment: This is a very detailed reply! It is very helpful and clarified my doubts, thank you @Dr.Kameleon.

Comment: @DankVader You're very welcome :)